# how to make hexagon shaped button in android?

Tags: android, button

I need to make buttons with hexagon image in android.From some tutorials i come to know that we need to make a class and we need to give name of that class in place of writing button in xml file.But i am not getting from where to start?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Using an image of a hexagon with transparent background will solve the problem. The image will appear as hexagon, although it is a rectangle.

You can call the method setOnClickListener() on any view, since it belongs to the view class.
Therefore you can create an ImageView that fits your needs and then call setOnClickListener to use it as a button.

Comment: that's where is the problem .I have trouble in creating hexagon shape not on making it to act as button

Comment: You can use an image of a hexagon with transparent background. Then you can put the image in an ImageView. With transparent background, the button appears as hexagon - however, the clickable area will be a rectangle

Comment: based on what you're asking, this answer is appropriate. Pretty much any view in android can act as a button as you can set OnClickListener to it. Once you have a view placed on a screen, you can setup image background, which in your case happens to be a hexagon with transparent edges.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public ShapeDrawable myFunction(){
        Path path = new Path();
        float stdW = 100;
        float stdH = 100;
        float w3 = stdW / 3;
        float h2 = stdH / 2;
        path.moveTo(0, h2);
        h2 -= 6 / 2;
        path.rLineTo(w3, -h2);         path.rLineTo(w3, 0); path.rLineTo(w3, h2);
        path.rLineTo(-w3, h2); path.rLineTo(-w3, 0); path.rLineTo(-w3, -h2);
        Shape s = new PathShape(path, stdW, stdH);
        ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable(s);
        Paint p = d.getPaint();
        p.setColor(0xffeeeeee);
        p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(6);

        return d;

    }
```

In your onClick:

```
 someView.setBackgroundDrawable(myFunction());
```

Comment: aakash i made a button now how this code will affect it.Means do i need to call this inside the function triggered on click of button or something else.Actually i am new to android.So please explain a bit :)

Comment: Its not working.Please check if i have dome some wrong .

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="click"/>

Comment: and this is for java file

Comment: public void click(View view)
{
 view.setBackgroundDrawable(myFunction());

}
public ShapeDrawable myFunction(){
    here your code
}

}

Comment: use  text.setBackground(myFunction()); instead. Also change the color in p.setColor(Color.RED);